# How to use parallel_tests with specific tags

Tags: ruby, testing, parallel-processing, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I'm using Ruby + Cucumber + Watir WebDriver to create functional tests for my web project. I've divided my scenarios by priorities using simple tags: @critical, @major, etc. I'm using Rake to run my features. I've created several tasks in my Rakefile.

Now I try to use parallel_tests gem to run my features in parallel mode. I've created special task 'parallel' in my Rakefile:

`task :parallel do
  'parallel_cucumber features -n 4'
end`

My question is: can I parallel my features execution AND use tags at the same time (for example run parallel_cucumber only for "@critical" scenarios in features)?

Comment: why should you not be able to do it?

Comment: Sorry, my question is not only 'can I?' but 'HOW can I?' too.

Comment: you question is very unspecific. it does not show what you tried or which errors you got. stackoverlow is not meant to let others do your homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create configuration called "parallel" in your cucumber.yml file and add all of the parameters from the other configurations (for example tags). After that you can run parallel_cucumber and it will use this configuration automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `-o` option. Try something like this:

```
parallel_cucumber features/ -n 4 -o '-r features -t @critical'
```

You can even use `ENV['tags']` to read from the command line, and pass that to the above inside your task.